# get a list of unique items from Random.choices function

Tags: python, random

I have a method that is using the random package to generate a list with certain probability for example:

```
import random

seed = 30
rand = random.Random(seed)
options_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
prob_weights = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.06]
result = rand.choices(option_list, prob_weights, k=4) # k will be <= len(option_list)
```

my problem is that `result` can hold two of the same item, and I want it to be unique.

I could make the `k` param much larger and then filter out the unique items but that seems like the wrong way to do that. I looked in the docs and I dont see that the choices function gets this kind of parameter.

Any ideas how to config random to return a list of **unique** items?

Comment: Wanting to get k unique items and at the same time giving weights doesn't make sense, that's why there is no such option.

Comment: `random.sample()`?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think it would make sense if the order matters. As for the answer, checkout numpy [random choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). It has an option to turn off replacement.

Comment: It is not at all clear what probability distribution on either vectors or subsets (which is it?) of size 4 you are trying to  generate. Please elaborate.

Comment: on a subset. if `k==len(option_list)` i'll expect to get `option_list` no matter what the probability is. when `k<len(option_list)` i would want to get a subset of `option_list`  
 generated using the proper probabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), which allows you to assign probabilities associated with each entry and also to generate random samples *without replacement*. The probabilities however must add up to one, you'll have to divide the vector by its `L^1-Norm`. So here's how you could do it:

```
import numpy as np
options_list = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
prob_weights = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.06])
prob_weights_scaled = prob_weights / sum(prob_weights)
some_length = 4 

np.random.choice(a=options_list, size=some_length, replace=False, p=prob_weights_scaled)
```

**Output**

```
array([2, 1, 6, 3])
```

Comment: my probabilities are normalized but do not add always exactly to 1. any way to get around that (even better i can use the random module). also, I need to use seed in choices

Comment: @NotSoShabby In your question, your probabilities add up to 0.53, so saying that they don't add up to exactly 1 seems like an understatement.

Comment: that was just an example from the top of my head. in the system they add up to ~.8 (in the cases I tested). Anyways they dont add up exactly to one

Comment: Yes @NotSoShabby you'll just need to divide by the sum or the norm 1 of the array